# Inheriting and extending Python bytearray

Tags: python, inheritance, arrays

I want to be able to write to a bytearray buffer and to clear it by calling a method, so I have a class that looks like this:

```
import struct

class binary_buffer(bytearray):
    def __init__(self, message=""):
        self = message
    def write_ubyte(self, ubyte):
        self += struct.pack("=B", ubyte)
        return len(self)
    def clear(self):
        self = ""
```

However, calling clear() does not seem to do anything at all. A sample output would look like this:

```
>>> bb = binary_buffer('')
>>> bb
bytearray(b'')  # As expected, the bytearray is empty
>>> bb.write_ubyte(255)
1  # Great, we just wrote a unsigned byte!
>>> bb
bytearray(b'\xff') # Looking good. We have our unsigned byte in the bytearray.
>>> bb.clear() # Lets start a new life!
>>> bb
bytearray(b'\xff') # Um... I though I just cleared out the trash?
```

Comment: As you've asked similar questions before I would like to make clear that the `self` variable is NOT a special variable in **python**. It is just another name that we happen to use for the `class instance`. You should see it as a variable containing your `instance` and not as a special variable.

Comment: @Wessie: I'm still quite new to this, but does my code as shown in the question above follow your description? I think it does, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
    self = ""
```

with

```
    self[:] = ""
```

Otherwise all you're doing is rebinding the `self` reference.

Similarly, the following doesn't do what you expect:

```
    self = message
```